# Changing the DataSource of UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm designing a UICollectionView that shows all products in my database.  When the user opens the collectionView, they are shown all products populated from my [Product] array in a custom CollectionViewCell.

My Product class has a `category` property that I want the user to be able to tap, and reload the collectionView showing a list of categories for the user to filter the data.  Similar to the iOS Photos app to view the photos by album though, preferably, I'd rather it started on all photos.

Is there any way to do this without implementing a second CollectionViewController?

Comment: have you tried changing data source of collection view?

Comment: How do I do that?  since my dataSource is my [Product] array which sets the rows and cell values I can't change the type of array to my categories.  Is there a way to set the dataSource and everything else to a different value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it by adding some indicator which you will change when the user type the category button, for example bool variable:

```
var showCategory = false
```

and in every data source / delegate method you need to check condition, for example:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if (showCategory) {
        return 10 // your logic to display data for categories
    } else {
        return 15 // your logic to display data for non categories
    }
  }


  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (showCategory) {
        return 10 // your logic to display data for categories
    } else {
        return 15 // your logic to display data for non categories
    }
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    if (showCategory) {
        // your logic to display data for categories
    } else {
        // your logic to display data for non categories
    }
    return cell
  }
```

Just remember when you want to show categories you should change the data source, set showCategory variable to true and call reload data method.

If you have more datasource/delegate method you should add the condition too.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Not sure why I never thought of such a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

As Arsian Asim suggested, change the data source of the collection view and then call `reloadData` on your CollectionView